# Cancelling a long running Rx stream

Tags: c#, system.reactive

If I have stream with a long running operation, something like:

```
inputStream.Select(n => Task.Run(() =>
{
    // Long running operation
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    return n * n;
}).ToObservable())
.Switch()
.Subscribe(result => 
{
    // Use result in some way
    Console.WriteLine(result);
});
```

How can I get a CancellationToken inside of the `Task.Run` call so that when `Switch` disposes the subscription of an in-flight calculation, it sets the CancellationToken as cancelled so I know to abort the calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Observable.StartAsync` method, e.g.

```
inputStream.Select(n => Observable.StartAsync((token => Task.Run(() =>
{
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // .. don't need to do anything
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        return n * n;

    }                   
}))))
.Switch()
.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

Alternatively, if you'll be producing multiple values you can use the `Observable.Create` overload that works with `Task` to get a CancellationToken. E.g.

```
inputStream.Select(n => Observable.Create<int>((observer, token) => Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        observer.OnNext(n * n);
    }

    observer.OnCompleted();
})))
.Switch()
.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

Inside of your task, you need to call `OnNext` to produce values. The return value of the task, if any, is ignored.